# How to find which record fails when you update 1000 records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Suppose we are updating 1000 records , and if the 10th record fails then how will we know which record has failed?

Comment: I don't consider this *easy*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the SAVE EXCEPTIONS or **[DML error logging](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=329)**, if you are on 10gR2 or later.